# Column in Sql dynamically change data every change of one of the column of choice

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm making an Enrollment System web based program. And my problem is that my style in updating the `CountStudentInSubject` by using an increment to the `CountStudentInSubject` Column in SQL. But when i delete the Student in the Subject the `CountStudentInSubject` is still the same.

Anybody have idea how I can do this?

**CODE in c#**

```
Status++;
SqlCommand command1 = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Subject SET Status = " + Status + "WHERE OfferCode = " + selectedOfferCode + ";", conn);
```

Comment: NEVER EVER use concatenated query, because you are vulnerable to [SQL Injection attack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection)

Comment: Where is the code where you delete students?

Comment: @Viru Actually i dont have a code for delete students. i just delete it in the SQL right away sir.

Comment: @dotnetom thank you for reminding me for that. What is the other way for that sir?

Comment: then you can use After Delete Triggers on stident table then subtract count in subject table provided there is some kind of relation between student and subject table.....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best way to solve your problem is using `Trigger`. A trigger is a special kind of stored procedure that automatically executes when an event occurs in the database server. For more information, please take a look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189799.aspx).

To avoid `SQL Injection Attack`, instead of concatenating string, you should use `Parameterized Query`. Look at [this example](http://software-security.sans.org/developer-how-to/fix-sql-injection-microsoft-.net-with-parameterized-queries) to know more about it.

Comment: thank you. Im not deploying it on-line but thank you for the lesson. Ill do it next time when i make one. This is a school project :)